# Where to start with JSON? (Closed)

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get started with JSON. I've set the link to the JSON.js file using a script link, and I've set my objects using JSON, but it returns no results at all when I try to refer to the object. The JSON doesn't seem to be working at all. If anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be appreciated. I've looked all over the internet and haven't found much to help me.

Thanks guys. The JSON website helped me figure it out

Comment: JSON is really just a subset of JavaScript. You should show some code and describe what isn't working about it, and in which browser(s).

Comment: Maybe you are confusing JSON with object literal notation. We could tell more with actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of links that might help:

http://secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp

[http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29)

Answer (score 2):

Get Firefox, get Firebug, learn to use it to see what javascript is being loaded, and where the errors are.

Oh, and post some code.

Comment: Also try running the JSON you sent through [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to make sure that it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look-see at this

http://json.org/

basically you need to understand that json is a way to stream javascript object literals and arrays from a  server to the client (and vice-versa).  Open up firebug/webkit and in the console try

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"test": 1}')
```

and you will see that obj is an object literal with a test property.

edit -- note that the link I provided mentions that json is a "is a lightweight data-interchange format" -- so its does not need to be javascript specific.  But I think in practice you will get the most mileage using json in conjunction with javascript.